# How to make triangle section separator

Tags: html, css, integration

I have to do the integration of a mockup. But I am wondering if there is a way to do it only in CSS.

We have a (diagonal) triangle section separator, and I don't know how to make them in CSS (except with image or svg). And if this is even possible?

My separator looks like this:
[image: separator].
(It's a huge rectangle triangle at the top of the section).

I'm speaking of the part at the top of the blue line here:

[image: blue_line].

Do you know if it's possible to do it with CSS rules?
And if so, how can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicae - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work

Comment: Thanks for the link. This and the zep_fan answer should do the trick :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do. Using `vw` (viewport-width) to span the entire container.

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 30px 100vw;
  border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
  }
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

You can attach this to a `:before` pseudo-selector on your container.

You will have to do some work for cross-browser compatibility however. See the [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) on this for more information and updates on supported browsers.

Comment: Thank you. This should do the trick easily.

Comment: I don't know if you saw my updated snippet; but I had the width set to 100% which was producing undesired results. Changing it to 0 is the correct solution.

Comment: Yes I saw this. In fact I read the [Paulie_D's link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work) and saw the width had to be to 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS3 method:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u7xyx03s/)

**HTML**

```
<section class="diagonal">
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #333;
    margin: 0px;
}
section {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:100px;
}
section:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
}
.diagonal {
    background: teal;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 3em;
}
.diagonal:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 3% 0;
    transform-origin: 3% 0;
    top: 0;
    left: -25%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 150%;
    height: 75%;
    background: inherit;
}
```

Comment: A bit more complex. But interesting way to do the trick.

Comment: @hornfl4kes Please know that `vw` CSS (your accepted answer) does have some browser support issues. [See Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: Yes I know, but for this project I don't want to be fully compatible. But thank you so much for your trick too :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolutely positioned border offset off the top of your container:

https://jsfiddle.net/Levde3kj/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}
.container .triangle {
     position: absolute;
     top: -25px;
     left: 0;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 0 0 25px 400px;
     border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;  
}
```